# Qualifier for Bean dont found name in @Service constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I am trying to call a method to set rest template values using OAuth2RestTemplate, I created a configure file in other part of the project (there is a core part of the project and an application part, no depency between them) that has a bean to OAuth2RestTemplate:

```java
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean(name = "oAuth2RestTemplateMbDev")
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(MbdevOAuth2Properties resource, Proxy proxy) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getRequestFactory(proxy);

        restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(getAccessTokenProvider(requestFactory));
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new MbdevResponseErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new MbdevHeadersInterceptor());

        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Bean(name = "oAuth2RestTemplate")
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(NexnetOAuth2Properties resource, Proxy proxy) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource);
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = getRequestFactory(proxy);

        restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(getAccessTokenProvider(requestFactory));
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new NexnetResponseErrorHandler());
        restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new NexnetHeadersInterceptor());

        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

This is the one I created it, the other already exist:

```java
@Bean(name = "oAuth2RestTemplateMbDev")
public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(MbdevOAuth2Properties resource, Proxy proxy)
```

So to be able to use 2 Bean for the same class I assign a name to be called using @Qualifier.

Like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.toggles.value", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MBdevOrderApiDataService implements OrderItemApiData {

    private URI resource;
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public MBdevOrderApiDataService(@Value("endpoints.value.endpoint") String resource,
                                    @Qualifier("oAuth2RestTemplateMbDev") OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.resource = URI.create(resource);
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public ListOrderItemApiDataDto getApiListData(String date, String productId, List<String> applicationStatus, String applicationId, String billingMetric, Boolean includeNonBillable) {

        ListOrderItemApiDataDto list = restTemplate.getForObject(resource, ListOrderItemApiDataDto.class);
        log.info("Data list");
        return null;
    }

}
```

so my problem is that each time i try to launch my system to test if this works this error message appears (check at the end of the post)

Can someone give me a hand?

**edit:
this is how is called in the orderController->**

```
private OrderService orderService;
private PoiOrderService poiOrderService;
private MBdevOrderApiDataService mBdevOrderApiDataService;

@Autowired
public OrderController(OrderService orderService, PoiOrderService poiOrderService, MBdevOrderApiDataService mBdevOrderApiDataService) {
    this.orderService = orderService;
    this.poiOrderService = poiOrderService;
    this.mBdevOrderApiDataService = mBdevOrderApiDataService;
}

@ApiOperation(value = "Get Data from API MbDev.")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "requestDate", dataType = "string", value = "The search date range from 'yyyy-MM'", defaultValue = "2021-12", paramType = "query")})
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_OK, message = "The petition to get data API Mbdev proceed correctly"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "The petition to get data API Mbdev could not be processed.", response = ExceptionResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN, message = "You don't have the necessary rights to use this endpoint. Please contact the admin."),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message = "System error.", response = ExceptionResponse.class)
}) //</editor-fold>

@PostMapping(path = "/orders/api/mb-dev", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseEntity<ListOrderItemApiDataDto> getExternalApiDataMbDev(@RequestParam(required = false) String requestDate) {
    List<String> applicationStatus = Arrays.asList(ApplicationStatus.BUSINESS.getValue(), ApplicationStatus.BUSINESS_TESTING.getValue());
    ListOrderItemApiDataDto dto = this.mBdevOrderApiDataService.getApiListData(requestDate,null, applicationStatus,null,null,true);
    return dto != null ? ResponseEntity.ok(dto) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

}
```

**edit-> full log:**

> 2022-02-01 15:51:25.695  WARN 25468 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException:
> Invalid bean definition with name 'oAuth2RestTemplate' defined in
> class path resource
> [com/tss/pago/application/configuration/RestTemplateConfig.class]:
> Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
> abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=restTemplateConfig;
> factoryMethodName=oAuth2RestTemplate; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
> [com/tss/pago/application/configuration/RestTemplateConfig.class]] for
> bean 'oAuth2RestTemplate': There is already [Root bean: class [null];
> scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3;
> dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=nexnetRestTemplateConfig;
> factoryMethodName=oAuth2RestTemplate; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
> [com/tss/pago/application/configuration/NexnetRestTemplateConfig.class]]
> bound. 2022-02-01 15:51:25.709  INFO 25468 --- [           main]
> ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The bean 'oAuth2RestTemplate', defined in class path resource
> [com/tss/pago/application/configuration/RestTemplateConfig.class],
> could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been
> defined in class path resource
> [com/tss/pago/application/configuration/NexnetRestTemplateConfig.class]
> and overriding is disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Try to remove `@ConditionalOnProperty` and if it helps then check that `feature.toggles.value` is set correctly.

Comment: Can you please add the `NexnetRestTemplateConfig` class? It seems you are trying to register two times a bean with exactly the same name.

Comment: I make some changes after I reading what @talex wrote, first I found that in the controller, 

> private MBdevOrderApiDataService mBdevOrderApiDataService;

 I was using the implementation not the service. The service didn´t have the anotation 

> @   Service.

And finally 

> @   ConditionalOnProperty

 had and incorrect value.
I change it all and it show a different error that said that, because OAuth2RestTemplate was the same name of method even if the Bean name was diferente that caused and error, after I change the project finally starts.  
Thanks for all your help

Comment: Either add the solution as an answer and accept it or simply delete the question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to pass OAuth2RestTemplate  in constructor parameter just use `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` like below and use restTemplate wherever you required. **Autowired** will automatically inject OAuth2RestTemplate  value you don't required to set it explicitly on constructor.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("oAuth2RestTemplateMbDev")
private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate
```

So your code look like this

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "feature.toggles.value", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MBdevOrderApiDataService implements OrderItemApiData {

    private URI resource;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oAuth2RestTemplateMbDev")
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate

   
    public MBdevOrderApiDataService(@Value("endpoints.value.endpoint") String resource) {
        this.resource = URI.create(resource);
        
    }

    @Override
    public ListOrderItemApiDataDto getApiListData(String date, String productId, List<String> applicationStatus, String applicationId, String billingMetric, Boolean includeNonBillable) {

        ListOrderItemApiDataDto list = restTemplate.getForObject(resource, ListOrderItemApiDataDto.class);
        log.info("Data list");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I already tried that and the result is the same.

Comment: can you post the entire error logs

Comment: Added at the end of the edit post